# Fitting a polygon in a image and finding the angles

Tags: python, image-processing, polygon, object-detection, scikit-image

I have an image of an object that I would like to fit a polygon and extract the internal angles:

[image]

I tried to do that fitting lines to the edges of the object using Hough lines from the 
[skimage package](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html).

After that I calculated the angles between the lines. I had more lines than the ones that fitted to the edges of the object, so I had to exclude these lines manually. I have to repeat the algorithm with a large series of images, so I wonder if there is another way that would be simpler and I could apply to an entire stack of images?

Comment: It should be obvious that you can't find angles in the upper half, even manually.

Answer (score 0):

To get angles between 2 lines you can check this post this gives some info -

[How to measure the angle between 2 lines in a same image using python opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673283/how-to-measure-the-angle-between-2-lines-in-a-same-image-using-python-opencv)

Do refine the edge detection used to get better results, share the actual image I can give it a try.